# Solve recurrence: T(n)=3T(2n/3)+1

Tags: runtime, big-o, recurrence

What is the runtime of a recurrence `T(n)=3T(2n/3)+1` and how did you get it?

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you. At least show what your failed analyses comes out to be, and we'll try to help fix that. But right now you could just be lying about "getting stuck" and typing in the above question is the only effort you've put into it so far.

Comment: I've been stuck for a little less than a week, and at one point I posted here on stack overflow, and did include my attempts (here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888827/trouble-trying-to-find-the-asymptotic-runtime-of-a-recurrence). Nobody responded, so I figured I would try again.

Answer (score 1):

This type of recurrences can be solved with a [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). Here `a=3`, `b=3/2` and `f(n) = 1`. Your `c = log1.5(3) = 2.709` And because `n^2.709` is bigger than `f(n)`, you fall into first case.

So the solution is `O(n^2.709)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). This is a lot easier than trying to solve the recurrence yourself, as you tried in your original question.

OTTOMH this should get you `T(n) = Theta(n^2.7)` (Case 1 of the Master Theorem).